# Godaddy Domain To Point To Home Web Server

Tags: apache, dns, xampp, ip, webserver

I have a home web server running in XAMPP on port 80. I access my website using my external IP.

I have a godaddy domain that I would like to point to my web host. I don't think domain forwarding is what I want because with this it just masks the URL and I want it to actually direct to the web host.

How do I make it so it points to my local web host on my server just like it did before when I had hosting through godaddy?

Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

Comment: This is a bad, bad idea, even assuming you know how to run a server safely and prevent intrusion into your home network. If you don't know how to do those things, it's a terrible idea.

Comment: So, I can't host myself?

Comment: It isn't *technically* impossible to host it from your home network but it is a really bad idea and will cause you many untold problems in the future.

Comment: So how do most people do it.. I thought people self hosted all the time.

Comment: @ThatGuy you *can* host yourself. It's just a bad idea. If you don't know - *really know* - what you're doing, it can be catastrophic. Imagine someone hacking your website and, from there, taking over every device on your network, logging all of the keystrokes on your computers, etc. This isn't some crazy scenario; it's a real risk of opening a hole in your network to let in inbound traffic. As James said, it can cause you a lot of problems down the road.

Comment: @ThatGuy self-hosting doesn't (usually) mean on an inside-the-firewall personal computer. It's more like getting a VPS or setting up designated boxes outside the home firewall. If you are not a true expert, you shouldn't even think about this. I have been running servers for decades now, and what you describe scares even me. Better plan: just host your site with a shared hosting provider or, if you really need it, get a VPS.